# How to upgrade version of terraform in windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

How to upgrade version of terraform in windows. Now i am using 0.9 and on windows using git bash. can someone help me with the process or commands.
Note: I did some google search but no use.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would read the [upgrade guides](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/index.html) written by Hashicorp to make upgrading versions transparent. In your case I would read both `0.10` and `0.11` as they're likely to have changes that will affect you.

Secondly, in addition to this test in isolation with later versions of Terraform, i.e. not using remote state file and in a sandbox environment.

Lastly, locate where the current Terraform binary is located, perhaps check your `Environment Variables` for a `PATH` that may lead to where the executable is, and replace that with the latest version of Terraform which you can download [here.](https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html)

Comment: Thank you! I found an answer! I removed the terraform path from system environment variables. also deleted the terraform from c:/windows/bin/terraform file

Answer (score 13):

I know you specified using bash but this is the first answer that comes up in searches so this is more FYI for future travelers.

To find the location of terraform.exe in powershell:

```
(get-command terraform.exe).Path
```

I had used [Chocolaty to install Terraform](https://chocolatey.org/packages/terraform) so to upgrade:

```
choco upgrade terraform
```

Comment: I have downloaded terraform exe as per terraform download page and kept in c:/terraform and updated the same in system environment path variable. When I check the terraform version it was not giving the correct version of the terraform which I just downloaded and kept in c:/terraform. By using the above command, I got to know I have already installed terraform using chocolatey and when I check the command terraform version it was giving the terraform version installed using chocolatey.

Answer (score 12):

This is using Git Bash on Windows

1. Download the latest version and unzip it
2. Navigate to that folder through your bash CLI
3. Now type which terraform
4. Copy the path of the terraform
5. Now type

   ```
   cp terraform.exe <your Terraform path>
   ```

   e.g. `cp terraform.exe /c/WINDOWS/System32/terraform`
6. Now check by using

   ```
   terraform --version
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
choco install terraform --version=0.12.14 --force
```

to install version that you like.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).